# Given a record, how to get the record's model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in several of my models:

The Poll.rb for instance:

```
def sanitize_html
    for column in Poll.content_columns  
    end
end
```

What I want to do is include this in my model_helpers which is included in models with:

```
include ModelHelpers
```

Problem is I have the model name hard coded in the method above:

```
for column in Poll.content_columns
```

How can I dry this out so instead of Poll, rails automatically finds the self.ModelName?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `self.class.content_columns` ?

Comment: That did it thanks, submit as an answer and I'll mark it

Comment: @muistooshort thanks :) I really don't like the SO feature that turns short answers into comments :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
self.class.content_columns
```

and it will call the class method, which is exactly what you want to do here. (writing a long winded explanation so this doesn't get turned into a comment. hehe)